# jqBootstrapValidation doesn’t show custom data-validation-required-message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use jqBootstrapValidation; it shows the default message instead of a custom message. Do I miss a `<div>` here ?

```
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="login_value" class="sr-only">Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login_value" name="juname" placeholder="Username" tabindex="1" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please Enter Username" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you forget to add the validation classes to your label.

```
<label for="login_value" class="sr-only control-label required">Username</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="login_value" name="juname" placeholder="Username" tabindex="1" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please Enter Username" />
```